# Is there a "Sitecore Lunch" online event happening regularly?

Tags: discussion, community-event

Are there any regularly occuring virtual events happening, that are not "traditional" User Groups?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. There are, in fact, two.

Sitecore Lunch America - happening every Friday of the week at 12.15PM ET

Sitecore Lunch Europe - happening every other Friday at 1PM CET

Links will be posted on Sitecore Community Slack